API call on Silent Push notification gets timeout/ lost internet connection when the app is not in use for more than 2 days
My iOS Swift app is receiving the silent push notification even if the is not in use for 2-3 days, however I've to call api to update user location when the silent push notification is received. After 2-3 days of inactive app API to update server is getting timeout 9 out of 10 times. if I open the app for a while it will work again normally for 2 days.
Server response time is fine no issue with low response time.
What I've to do to get API success in inactive app for 2-3 days
I'm using URLSession for api calling
func sendLoc(data: [String: Any]) {
  
    let url = URL(string: "https://abcd.com/api/profile/update_location")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    var accessToken = UserDefaultsManager.shared.getBearerToken()
  
    request.setValue("Bearer \(accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    var parameters: [String: Any] = [:]
    
    for (key, value) in data {
        parameters[key] = value
    }

    request.httpBody = parameters.percentEncoded()
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard
            let data = data,
            let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            error == nil
        else {  // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error", error ?? URLError(.badServerResponse))
            return
        }
        
        guard (200 ... 299) ~= response.statusCode else { // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 2xx, but is \(response.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(LocationResponse.self, from: data)
            print(responseObject)
        } catch {
            print(error) // parsing error
            if let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("responseString = \(responseString)")
            } else {
                print("unable to parse response as string")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}


You should call beginBackgroundTask as soon as you receive the push notification and end the background task once your server update is complete.  If your app only supports iOS 15 and up (which I think is a reasonable position these days) then you should use a location push service extension

Hi @Paulw11, I've requested for the location push service meanwhile I'm using silent push.
If the user has forcefully killed the app will this beginBackgroundTask work, as long as I researched I found that background fetch will not work if the user forcefully killed the app.

It's not a background fetch or BackgroundTask. It's simply an indication to iOS that your app is doing a small amount of work that should be allowed to complete before your app is suspended.  It is nothing to do with launching your app.

@Paulw11 I tried your suggested beginBackgroundTask solution, however the result is same, If the app is inactive/not in use for 2-3 the api gets timeout.

I think you will need to wait for the location push entitlement for a reliable solution.  Background execution on IOS cannot be guaranteed.
